# For loop efficiency in python

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop, function-call

When a for loop is used iterate through a list in python. If we use a functions in as shown below.

```
def fun():return [1,2,3]

for i in fun():print(i)
```

Will the **function call** take place **for every iteration** or it take place **only once** and the list is stored in memmory throughout the execution of loop??

Comment: Why don't you put a breakpoint or print statement inside the `fun` function, and find out?

Comment: that was an incredible idea .Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple question.Sorry for that. I put a break point on the function and found that the function is called only once and the returned list is used for further iteration